# Kernel Errors Present: EXT4-fs

Tags: linux, kernel, ext4

Logwatch is giving me the following error:

```
WARNING:  Kernel Errors Present
EXT4-fs (sda1): error count: 4 ...:  1 Time(s)
EXT4-fs (sda1): initial error at 1350482172: e ...:  1 Time(s)
EXT4-fs (sda1): last error at 1350941030: e ...:  1 Time(s)
```

and /var/log/kern.log gives me this:

```
Feb  3 17:01:37 localhost kernel: [172881.883105] EXT4-fs (sda1): error count: 4
Feb  3 17:01:37 localhost kernel: [172881.883110] EXT4-fs (sda1): initial error at 1350482172: ext4_reserve_inode_write:4475
Feb  3 17:01:37 localhost kernel: [172881.883114] EXT4-fs (sda1): last error at 1350941030: ext4_remount:4428
```

When I run fsck it says that the disk is fine.  Can anyone explain in more detail what the kernel error is, and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not actually an error: that's a log noting the current error count for the device within the specified timeframe (epoch time 1350482172 - 1350941030). [Here's a more involved description of these lines by Ted Ts'o (ext2/3/4 maintainer)](https://lkml.org/lkml/2010/9/26/105). The long story made short is that LogWatch really shouldn't be alerting you on these lines; they're informational, and not indicative of a problem.